# Gcc uses sqrt without including math.h

Tags: c, gcc

Anyone knows why this c program compiles and uses the sqrt of math.h?

this would output 2.236068

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math_utils.h"

int main(void){
  printf("%f\n", sqrt(5));
  return 0;
}
```

math_utils.h

```
#ifndef MATH_UTILS_Hs
#define MATH_UTILS_Hs

double sqrt(double number){
  return number + 5;
}

#endif // MATH_UTILS_Hs
```

I am currently using mingw GCC on windows

Comment: GCC have a built-in `sqrt` function, it probably replaces your call with a call to its built-in function. Since you define that function it should really use your definition instead, maybe a bug in GCC? What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: Im currently using 4.8.3, I tried removing math_utils.h  and it would give me this error `main.c:5:18: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sqrt' [enabled by default]`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I believe gcc assumes that whatever definition of a recognized function is in scope, it will always do what gcc thinks the function should do.

Comment: From section 7.1.3 of (my free draft copy of) the standard: "If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined." That is, sqrt can't be used as the name of your function. So it seems to be undefined behavior rather than a bug in GCC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gcc performs an optimization where it expects standard library functions to behave like the standard says to turn calls into the C standard library into more efficient machine code. For example, it's likely that gcc emits a single `fsqrt` instruction for your `sqrt()` call, never calling your custom `sqrt()` at all.

You can turn off this behaviour by supplying `-fno-builtin` to turn this optimization off for all recognized functions or by supplying `-fno-builtin-function` to turn off this optimization for `function` only. For example, `-fno-builtin-sqrt` would make gcc honour your non-standard `sqrt()`.

Comment: you we're right mate, it works. thanks for the explanation.