# What are the GNU built-in functions?

Tags: c, gcc, built-in

What are the GNU built-in functions? 
Are they functions that call already implemented functions of the hardware? So do they call functions from kernel?
Do for example differ a normal sqrt() function from the math.h library from the builtin_sqrt() function?

Comment: "Also" No, this is already too broad IMO. Ask one question per question. However, these particular questions seem fairly easily answered by reading documentation instead of asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [GNU Compiler Collection Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html#Target-Builtins),

> On some target machines, GCC supports many built-in functions specific to those machines. Generally these generate calls to specific machine instructions, but allow the compiler to schedule those calls.

These are machine-specific, they don't have anything to do with the kernel.

There is already an answer about the difference between the builtin `sqrt()` vs the one in `math.h`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798834/8507637

Comment: So ..Glibc functions are different from built in functions. Glibc functions, are functions that come from this library, and built_in functions are machine-specific. Have I understood well?